# How do I print a selected list item from my MySQL database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a menu with a category called animals. I access the MySQL database like so for the animals.

```
include_once 'config.inc';
$mysqli=new mysqli($mysql_host, $user, $password, $database);
$query="select distinct name from animals";
$res=$mysqli->query($query);
while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc()) {
    print "{$row['name']}";
echo "</li>", "<li>";
```

I can get all the animals to print as list items with no problem. Now I want to use php to print out the animal that I click on. However, when I call this php file shown below, only the first list item will print properly. Please help

```
<?php
include_once 'config.inc';
$mysqli=new mysqli($mysql_host, $user, $password, $database);
$query="select distinct name from animals";
$res=$mysqli->query($query);
$row=$res->fetch_assoc(); 
echo "{$row['name']} selected";
```

Comment: Do you have record what you select?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
if ($res = $mysqli->query($query)) {
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        echo $row['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how you can echo the value. Now give the code which we have to compare with DB record to make it selected.

Comment: This causes me to print all the items instead of just the selected one. This is the output: selectedtiger selectedlion selecteddog selectedccat.

Comment: Yes, but give the code from which i can compare the value and make it selected

Comment: I guess I don't have that yet..any hints on how to do it?

Comment: You have name which you have click on?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether my answer is true or not, I am new in PHP, too.

Could you please try this one?

```
$query = "SELECT distinct name FROM animals";
$query_result = $sqli->query($query);
$query_row = $query_result->fetch_assoc();
$new = $query_row['name'];
echo $new;
```

Comment: It still only prints if I select the first item. Thank you for your help though.